# The correct way to display a workflow elements in a web page

Tags: javascript, jquery, visualization

I'm trying to create a web app that would display some kind of a workflow. The notation is not important, let's say it's activity diagram (e.g. https://i.stack.imgur.com/J3bmE.png).
The flow will be defined in a JSON format.
So, I'm wondering which approach is the best? Should I use a template engine (e.g. handlebars) with jQuery? Or is there any library that would enable the drawing of custom images?
Any suggestions are highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, if I understod you want to draw and store some workflow diagrams.

Then you have some awesome framework based on canvas(html5) [Raphaëljs](http://raphaeljs.com/) and [Fabricjs](http://fabricjs.com).

And all of them can be stored in a database, I suggest the couchDB, that is a RESTFul nosql database document(json) based.

Comment: Thank you for your response! Storing the data is of no problem. I have a server side for that. It's just displaying the flow in form of a workflow. I'll check both of proposed libraries!

Comment: unfortunately, neither raphaeljs nor fabricjs did not meet my expectations... I found more luck developing my own 'framework' by using native HTML5 support for SVG. Thank you none the less!

Comment: So, if you want to use svg, I think that [draw.io](http.draw.io) is the best choice, because you can draw UML diagrams and save to svg.